# getting next item in beatiful Soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

With Beautiful soup I need to detect the meaning of one expression. From the many definitions, only one is needed. In the Beautiful soup the contents is like this:

```html
<strong>occhio della testa</strong><br/>
loc.s.m <br/>
<span class="mu"title="">CO</span><span style="color:#000"> </span><br/>
follia<br/>
<strong>pagare un occhio della testa</strong><br/>
loc.v.<br/>
<span class="mu"title="">CO</span><span style="color:#000"> </span><br/>
strapagare<br/>
<strong>passare per la testa</strong><br/>
loc.v.<br/>
<span class="mu" title="">CO</span><span style="color:#000"> </span><br/>
passare per la mente<br/>
<strong>perdere la testa</strong><br/>
loc.v.<br/>
<span class="mu" title="">CO</span><span style="color:#000"> </span><br/>
entrare in uno stato di confusione mentale; impazzire, spec. fig.: ha perso la testa per quella donna, se ne è perdutamente innamorato<br/>
<strong>
```

What I need from the above text is :

```
pagare un occhio della testa:strapagare
```

I tried this

```
# list of expressions that I need their meaning
myitems = ['pagare un occhio della testa', '....' , '....']

for ex in myitems:
    ws = ex.split()
    li = ""
    url = "https://mydictionary/" + ws[-1]+ ""
    if urllib.request.urlopen(url):
        htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile, 'lxml')
        txt = soup.text
        if ex in txt:
           li = '%s = %r' % (es, soup.next_siblings)
    print(li)
```

This code gives only the ex. Can someone help?

Comment: Ciao! You should provide the structure of the html or the correct url in order to make your question solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how regular the structure is but for the above you can use the following (bs4  4.7.1):

```
soup.select_one('strong:contains("pagare un occhio della testa") ~ span + span').next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()
```

Comment: QHarr> 'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.')
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: Apologies. The above requires bs4 4.7.1 the latest

Comment: > QHarr: can I use a variabile instead in select_one('strong:contains("pagare un occhio della testa")? like this: select_one('strong:contains([ex for ex in myintems]")

Comment: will you only want one term per page and will each page have a similar layout?

Comment: Yes, there will be one term per page

Comment: And the above with a var would be https://pastebin.com/BAv6v5T4  but this would only work with regular repeating structure. We would need to see more html.

Comment: I just updated the pastebin to indicate you would be creating new soup object within loop before attempting each select